# Merge develop into master

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, branch

I'm merging `develop` into `master` though a website (e.g `gitlab`).
Squash commits into 1 commit is a feature proposed by gitlab and I used it.

**Problem**: When I do new changes on `develop` (and being sure there is no conflict with `master`), it's not possible to make a merge request without conflict. I guess `master` and `develop` have different histories so it requires several commands more to make `develop` ready to be merged again into `master`

Should I fast-forward rebase `master` into `develop`? Recreate the branch `develop` based on `master` or another process?

Comment: I don’t think there’s such a thing as a fast-forward rebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, in order to keep a clean merge history, doing a `git rebase` on the `develop` branch is desirable. That is how the Linux kernel expects things, for example.

So you would do something like the following:

(Assuming you are on your `develop` branch and master is in sync with `origin/master`)

```
git rebase master
# Resolve any conflicts and commit
git checkout master
git merge develop
```